# How to use precision in gmp-library?

Tags: c++, double, precision, gmp

How to use precision in gmp library?

Trying to find something like `set precision()` in double, float.

Actually, i need to compare my expression with null, but bound in task is too big to use float or double. Need your help!

Comment: Please do not use the MPF layer of GMP for any new code, use the MPFR library instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information about initializing and setting precision is available [in the GMP docs](https://gmplib.org/manual/Initializing-Floats.html). It sounds like you are looking for

> Function: void mpf_set_prec (mpf_t rop, mp_bitcnt_t prec)
>
> Set the precision of rop to be at least prec bits. The value in rop will be truncated to the new precision.
>
> This function requires a call to realloc, and so should not be used in a tight loop.